# Stuck with linear algebra proof! Who show $\langle ix,y\rangle = i\langle x,y\rangle$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume $\langle x,y\rangle = 1/4(\|x+y\|^2-\|x-y\|^2+i\|x+iy\|^2-i\|x-iy\|^2)$. If $\|\|$ satisfy the parallelogram equation it is possible to show that $\langle x,y\rangle$ defines an inner product. I showed it for the real case. I wanted to prove $i\langle x,y\rangle =\langle ix,y\rangle$ but fail. How to prove it?

Comment: Well, what happens when you plug $<ix,y>$ into the definition of the form?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\langle ix,y\rangle=\frac14\left(||ix+y||^2-||ix-y||^2+i||ix+iy||^2-i||ix-iy||^2\right)$$

and now use that

$$\begin{align*}ix+y&=i\left(x+\frac yi\right)=i\left(x-iy\right)\\
x-iy&=i\left(x-\frac yi\right)=i\left(x+iy\right)\\
x+iy&=i\left(\frac xi+y\right)=i\left(-ix+y\right)=-i(ix-y)\\
x-iy&=i\left(\frac xi-y\right)=i\left(-ix-y\right)=-i(ix+y)\end{align*}$$

and from here

$$||ix+y||=||x-iy||\;,\;\;||x+iy||=||ix-y||\;,\ldots\;etc.$$